# SharePoint Workflow Task Forms - Different form for each step of the workflow. How?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, custom

I am fairly New to SharePoint Workflows. I have created an approval workflow that has 4 task review steps. The business process dictates, that step/task 3 of the workflow will have a *different form* based on a form selection from previous task input.
I don't know how to present the user with different task forms based on results from the previous form. Can anyone shed light on this for me?

Step 1: Assigns a parallel task

Step 2: Task form should contain a dropdown to indicate

Options:

1. Skip Management or
2. Normal flow

Step 3: If Option 1 is chosen Present the user with same form as step 1 ELSE present another form

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through the use of Content Types.  Create a Content Type for each form you need.  Next, setup a workflow with a condition to look at the input that dictates the form to be used in the next step.  As an action to this condition, use a Set Field in Current Item action and set the Content Type ID to the form you want them to use.  Next, send a workflow email to the edit form to the next assigned to person in the workflow.

Alternatively, since the GUID for the content type is part of the URL string, you could just get the link directly to the edit form for that content type and use this as the URL to the form in our workflow email to the assigned to person.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I hate to ask this, but what do you mean by "Create a Content Type for each form you need." How does one go about doing that? I see the Content Types section of the library setting page, and I see that I can add content types. Do I create a content Type = "form" for each form I need to create?
Thank You

Comment: Yep, that's what you do.  You can setup new content types at the site level, then add them to the list where you want to use them.

Comment: I am missing something or, just not understanding the steps. I still don't know how to apply the forms to the various steps of the workflow.

Comment: Once you have the content types setup and added to your list, you have the ability to add and remove fields from each so long as they are available fields associated to the list.  From there, you just build out the 4 forms you need.  Once you have all the forms setup, just build the workflow to toggle (set field Content Type ID) to the appropriate form per the next step in the process/workflow.  This will make it so that form pulls up in that content type the next time it's opened. Embed link to edit form in the workflow email.  When they click it, it'll open the form particular to them.

Comment: Still Struggling: How do I add a content Type for each form? I added the content type "Form" but SP only allows me to do that 1 time.
I have created a form for each step, but I am uncertain how to modify them accordingly and/or reference that form in the Workflow conditions.
Once I understand this process I feel I will be able to create so many useful tools. Thank You in advance for any/all assistance with this.

Comment: You can find information online about how to use content types.  Once you get more familiar with how they work, it'll start to make more sense.    Once you understand that, you'll just change which content type the form will open in inside your workflow, which you can do with the Set Field action in the workflow.  So basically, when User X does Y set Content Type ID to ContentTypeName, send email.  That'll make it so the next person in the chain will open it in the content type they need for them to continue the process/approvals.